# Permanently hide title bar

Tags: android, android-titlebar

I want to permanently hide title. I mean: when I hide title bar and then swipe I see my title bar.So, I want to swipe and **do not** see my title bar. I've tried to use `onKeyDow()` but it didn't work. Do somebody have any idea how to do this?
This is how I hide title bar:

```
this.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

And this is onKeyDown() method:

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Check android:windowNoTitle style

Comment: What has the onKeyDown() have to do with anything here? :/

Comment: Don't do it programatically, do it in your manifest.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for ? http://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html

Comment: @user2819864 I just wanted to disable touch events. So, if there are no touch events then there are no actions and if there are no actions then action of appearing of title bar doesn't count.

Comment: @chintan-soni Thanks, but immersion won't work. Because, in that document on which you gave me a reference said:"When the user swipes inward in a system bars region, the system bars **reappear and remain visible**.".But I need to hide it permanently. So, when my app is opened title bar is hidden.

Comment: @mah I don't know why but my Theme.NoTitleBar doesn't work for my Activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Permanently disable or hide the status bar (it's called `status bar`, not title bar) or the navigation Keys would have a huge security flaw on the system. That would allow malicious applications to hijack the system. So the answer is:

No, you cannot do that!

Answer (score 0):

Do this in your `onCreate()` method.

```
// To Remove title bar
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

// To Remove notification bar
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

//then set layout using setContentView
```